# How can I present a UIDatePicker from inside a custom UITableCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom cell that contains a textField with a date in it and a button "ChangeDate".

I want to present a new view with a UIDatePicker when the user decides to change the date. My problem is that the cell is not a controller.

I tried somehow to make the parent controller present the new view but failed. I am not sure if that is a good idea or what I'm doing wrong.

Please advise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PickerViewController *pickerView = [[[UIPickerViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:pickerView animated:YES];
```

should do the trick, where PickerViewController is a UIViewController subclass with a pickerView and associated datasource/delegate methods.

Comment: It doesn't because this code runs inside a UITableViewCell that doesn't recognize self.navigationController.
The main problem is that I habdle the button click in a UITableViewCell but needs functionality of its parent view controller.

Comment: Its a subclass of UITableCell? and  [self.parentViewController.navigationController presentModalViewController: animated:] doesn't work? maybe set a breakpoint, and see if the viewController Outlets are set to Nil?

Comment: error: request for member 'parentViewController' in something not a structure or union

Comment: perhaps the easiest solution is to setup a navigationController property on the cell, and passing the value in when the cell is initialized.